# The meaning or the usage of The phrase " I'm beginning to think ( that) ... "

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

When a native American English speaker says the following phrase

> I'm beginning to think ( that ) ...

I still don't really know if they always used it in the same way regardless of whatever kind of context it's  used in. But I'll provide you with the context in which it's been used in (Just in case it has more than one possible use or meaning).

[It's been used in in the beginning of the 1st ep of a Japanese anime series that some of you have probably heard of and watched, called "Ouran HighSchool Host club"](https://youtu.be/Frr2r_6km-M)

I think the context begins from "1:17m" to "1:57m".

Comment: Note that "Native American" usually refers to someone who is ethnically [American Indian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States).  Instead you can say something like *"A native English speaker from America"*, to remove any confusion.

Comment: I see. I should be more careful next time , How about now?? Is it any clearer now ? And are u a native Am Eng Speaker yourself? got any Possible answer for me here or maybe even some Possibly useful tips that could help me out on this ? And tanks for that!!

Comment: I am a native English speaker, and I am American, but I'm not Native American  :)   In any case I wouldn't worry about who is answering your question.  The community will upvote a correct answer from *any* source, and downvote those that are not correct.  After all, there are many non-native English speakers whose English is far superior to many native speakers.  Also, I think this is a common English expression, not American slang.

Comment: I see. But does that mean that u cant really help me at all here for now with my Question Here or wat? I mean, since you're a native Am.Eng Speaker yourself. I'm Just trying to see here if u Native Am.Eng Speakers really use it in only one possible way regardless of what the context might be said in. U see , i Just started watching the 1st ep of this Jap Anime Series and I'm trying to learn and understand some English along the way. And i only prefer an answer from a native Am.Eng Speaker only because i wouldn't really risk getting any incorrect or incomplete answer from a non-native one.

Comment: I can't watch the video you link, as it's been blocked here due to copyright.  Anyway, I'm unclear why this is confusing for you.  Are you asking the difference between *"I'm beginning to think ..."* and *"I'm thinking ..."*?

Comment: Oh!! Okay, no i was only  asking if it has only one possible use or maybe more , i mean that regardless of what the context might be said or used in , its meaning doesn't change at all. But i'd also really Like To know the différence in usage/meaning   between " I'm thinking ..." and " I'm beginning to think that ... " .

Comment: Please refrain from using "jap". It is a racial slur targeting several groups of people. It is not a good idea to use it, ever, as a shorthand or even in chatspeak. I have changed it to "**Japanese**"

Comment: I'm really so Sorry, i swear i had no idea ever before. I also really didn't thought it is considered to be that serious to be not allowed To be used , but from now on of course i'll refrain from using it , and again I'm really really Sorry for that, i'll try to be more careful next time. I Just wanted To express my apologize and I'm not expecting u at all to accept my apologize , since i think I'm partly responsible for wat i did And that i should and could have been more careful.

Answer (score 4):

The common English phrase "I'm beginning to think that ..." is kind of a *standard* or *set* phrase, and the meaning does not normally change with context.  It is not in any way a uniquely American expression, as it's used by all English speakers.  It simply means:

> I have recently had the particular thought that ...

or

> My thoughts have recently included certain things such as ...

This structure can be used with many cognitive verbs:

> I'm beginning to **feel** that ...
>
> I'm beginning to **understand** that ...
>
> I'm beginning to **suspect** that ...

The difference between "I'm beginning to think that ..." and "I'm thinking that ..." is the nuance of *recent* or *just started*.  It often implies a *change in thought* based on new information.

> And yesterday I was sure I tasted arsenic in my afternoon tea.  I can't be sure, Holmes, but **I'm beginning to think** that my wife doesn't love me any more.

Comment: Tanks a lot for your help Andrew !! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: + 1 but You might want to add: in any variety of English. It is most definitely not just "American" English.

Comment: @Lambie Oh!! okay then,  Tanks for letting me know that!!